# PHP comment system and login system

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a comment system on my website http://gamehup.ga/new-browser-games/god-war.php. Right now the visitors can comment a link to somewhere else, what I want is when someone comments an URL, it needs to be approved by the admin of the site.

And I have login system I want to make the minimum for the password that someone can enter when they sign up.

And another thing, I have edit comment button but when you click it you will be sent to another page to edit it. I want to know if it possible to make it on the same page.

Comment: One question at a time works best here

Comment: This is either "too broad" or "unclear" anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another column in table beside comment and update it using admin page, set either 0 for unapproved and 1 for approved value of that table , according to that column value comment get shown on post!